# Rails 5 Invalid Object attribute on Save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a Search model with a HABTM relationship with an Area model.

When I try to conduct a search, I am getting this error on localhost:3000:

```
    1 error prohibited this search from being saved:
 - Areas is invalid
```

Relevant code from Search Controller:

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_search, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :require_admin, only: [:index]

def create
    @search = Search.new(search_params)
    @search.max_price = search_params["max_price"].gsub('$', '').gsub(',', '')
    @contact = Contact.new #in case it gets rerouted back to search#new

    respond_to do |format|
      if @search.save 
        if @search.school_slug.present?
          #           # format.html { redirect_to @school(:search_id => @search.id), notice: "#{@school.name} search updated"}
          @school = School.find_by(slug: @search.school_slug)
          p @school.name
          p @school.id
          # format.html { redirect_to @school(:search_id => @search.id), notice: "#{@school.name} search updated"}
          format.html { redirect_to school_path(slug: @school.slug, city: @school.city.parameterize.truncate(80, omission: ''), :search_id => @search.id), notice: "#{@school.name} search updated"}
        else
          format.html { redirect_to @search, notice: 'Search was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @search }
        end 
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @search.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_search
      @search = Search.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def search_params
      params.require(:search).permit(:school_id, :beds, :max_price, :user_id, :name, :district_id, :city_id, :email_me, :rental, :grade, :school_slug, area_ids: [], :prop_type => [])
    end
end
```

I tried to create a search in the console with a similar outcome:

```
irb(main):004:0> a = Search.new(beds: "3", max_price: "450000", area_ids:["1","2"])
  Area Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "areas".* FROM "areas" WHERE "areas"."id" IN (?, ?)  [["id", 1], ["id", 2]]
=> #<Search id: nil, beds: 3, max_price: 450000, prop_type: nil, user_id: nil, name: nil, area_id: nil, school_id: nil, district_id: nil, city_id: nil, email_me: nil, rental: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, grade: nil, school_slug: nil>
irb(main):005:0> a.areas
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Area id: 1, name: "N", created_at: "2018-05-24 12:24:16", updated_at: "2018-10-10 16:22:16", msa_id: 1, state_id: nil>, #<Area id: 2, name: "NW", created_at: "2018-05-24 12:24:16", updated_at: "2018-10-10 16:22:16", msa_id: 1, state_id: nil>]>
irb(main):006:0> a.save
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  Msa Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "msas".* FROM "msas" WHERE "msas"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Msa Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "msas".* FROM "msas" WHERE "msas"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
=> false
irb(main):007:0> a.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007fb245504958 @base=#<Search id: nil, beds: 3, max_price: 450000, prop_type: nil, user_id: nil, name: nil, area_id: nil, school_id: nil, district_id: nil, city_id: nil, email_me: nil, rental: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, grade: nil, school_slug: nil>, @messages={:areas=>["is invalid"]}, @details={:areas=>[{:error=>:invalid}, {:error=>:invalid}]}>
```

I tried removing the Msa association with no change in the error. I also tried creating an Area controller and whitelisted every object attribute with no change in the error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the Area controller and model per comment below:

```
class AreasController < ApplicationController

  def index(:msa_id)
    @areas = Area.where(msa_id: params[:msa_id])
  end

  def show
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_area
      @area = Area.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def area_params
      params.require(:area).permit(:name, :msa_id, :state_id, district_ids:[], search_ids:[], county_ids:[])
    end
end

class Area < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :districts
  has_many :counties
  has_and_belongs_to_many :searches
  belongs_to :msa
  belongs_to :state

end
```

And below are the database columns from the schema.rb:

```
create_table "searches", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "beds"
    t.integer "max_price"
    t.string "prop_type"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "area_id"
    t.integer "school_id"
    t.integer "district_id"
    t.integer "city_id"
    t.boolean "email_me"
    t.boolean "rental"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "grade"
    t.string "school_slug"
  end
```

Search model added per comment below:

```
class Search < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :areas

end
```

Comment: Could you post the validations for the area model, if any?

Comment: Chris, no validations in the Area model, but I've posted the relationships above.

Comment: As an aside, permitting parameters in a controller only matters within that controller and only for doing "mass assignment" with methods like `update`.

Comment: Okay, the next thing to check would be the columns in the database.  I would guess either a column is being moved into an invalid state (e.g. NULL, when the column specifies NOT NULL) or something is violating referential integrity.

Comment: I added the schema to show the columns, but now I'm thinking you are suggesting I go into the actual database.  I'll have to research how to do that.

Comment: One question: regarding `areas` for example. `areas` have many `districts`. Though when creating a new area you pass `district_ids` to the new instance. Can you elaborate on this ? Because if `Area` is the parent of `District` it is the district instance that should hold an `area_id`, not the way round. Children refer to parents.

Comment: Maxence, I think you are looking at the Search model, which has a district_id.  Area does not have a district_id column, but it does permit params for district_ids: [] because an area has_many district_ids.

Comment: Chris, I downloaded an Sqlite3 database viewer and started looking through the data.  It turns out that the areas I was selecting all had state_id = null.  I updated by adding a state_id to each and now its working!  I don't understand why, but at least I can move on. Thank you!

Comment: @tomb yes regarding `area` model. If, as you say, area has many district id, why do you pass those district IDs in the area permitted params ? They can't do anything with that. It is the district record that holds a reference to an area with an Area id...

Comment: @Maxence, perhaps the district_ids don't need to be in the permitted params, thanks for the comment.

Comment: Same for `search`. You have an `area_id` that you can populate with a single area id, which is the parent of search. Though you don't have any record for `area_ids` which is what you try to save. You are kinda mixing the `search`model relationships (parents and children) and some details of the search (different areas...). You should rethink the whole database design and really thinks of the data that different models hold, and their relationships which is two different things ...

Comment: Actual when you create a new search in the console: `a = Search.new(beds: "3", max_price: "450000", area_ids:["1","2"])`, I am not even sure how Rails can return a valid instance of `search` as `area_ids` is not a valid field for this model...

Comment: Can you edit your question with the model `search`?

Comment: @Maxence, in a HABTM relationship you don't need a column `:area_ids`.  Rails automatically creates a join table of foreign keys for the two models, so you get search.areas and area.searches just by adding HABTM in the two models.

Answer (score 0):

After your `Search.new` the Rails console returns this:

```
=> #<Search id: nil, beds: 3, max_price: 450000, prop_type: nil, user_id: nil, name: nil, area_id: nil, school_id: nil, district_id: nil, city_id: nil, email_me: nil, rental: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, grade: nil, school_slug: nil>
```

Note the `area_id: nil` attribute on the returned object.
You specify `area_ids`, plural, but the model has an `area_id` column, singular, which isn't set when you call new, causing an invalid relation error.
I don't know what your Searches model looks like but something isn't right, and I'd guess that's why you're getting this error...

Comment: Thanks for your comment James.  There used to be a belongs_to relationship between Area and Search (hence the area_id in the Search model), but now that relationship has changed to HABTM, and as a result the area_id foreign key is ignored by rails when searching for Search.areas

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull with the relationships and the models data.

When model `whatever` has many `things` then models should looks like :

```
class Whatever < ApplicationRecord
has_many :things
end


class Thing < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :whatever
end
```

This has one effect on your tables: when you create the `Thing` table you have to add this line in the thing migration: `t.references :whatever, index: true, foreign_key: true` which will create a field called `whatever_id` in the `things` table.

This is kind of a convention to name fields refering to parents like `parent_id`.

Now regarding your case, I think `Search` shoud be the child of a `User` (it is the user who crerate searches) but not many other models than this one...

If you want to store the details of the search, then create a specific field with an explicit name like `search_content` in which you can save a hash of the search details : `{'beds': 3, 'max_price': 45000, 'areas' : [1,2]}`.

Of course, you can also create a relationship between search and area with a HABTM relationship.

In this case, Once your search record is created and saved:

```
s = Search.new(user_id: 1, search_details: {'beds': 3, 'max_price': 45000, 'areas': [1,2]})
s.save
```

Then you can add the areas rerlationship:

```
s.search_details['areas'].each do |area_id|
  s << Area.find(area_id)
end
```